# -- is there a way to copy up to a search term, _including_ the term?

Tags: vim, copy-paste

If I have the following words

```
cat Oliver Louis
```

and the cursor is on "c", I can copy up to the beginning of Louis with `y/Louis<CR>` (where "CR" is the enter key), which will copy the string "cat Oliver ".

Is there a way to copy the search term, "Louis", as well, for a copied string of "cat Oliver Louis"? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `/e` modifier: `y/Louis/e<CR>`. If you want to repeat the last search pattern, just leave it out: `y//e<CR>`.

```
:help search-offset
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the `/` search is *exclusive*, it will select everything up to the match, but not including the match. (check `:help exclusive`)

A more convenient way might be to use the *inclusive* `f` and `t` motion commands.

With the following line:

```
cat Oliver Louis
```

typing `yfs` in normal mode will yank everything up to the letter "s", or in this case, `cat Oliver Louis`

Obviously, this isn't as convenient if the line is something like

```
cat Assassins Scissors
```

There are too many s's. In this case you might want to go into visual mode and either repeat the inclusive `f` search motion by tapping `;` until you reach the last s. Or, as you suggested above, simply use `w` preceded by the number of words you'd like to copy. In this case `y3w` will work.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use look-behind assertions... but the syntax is rather ugly!

```
y/\(Louis\)\@<=
```

This doesn't look for Louis, but for a position preceded by the string Louis.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am looking for something convenient; I think it might be easier to go into visual mode, search for the term and hit "w" or the like -- it's less mental overhead. Thanks anyway though.

Comment: With `\zs`, it would have been easier -> `y/Louis\zs`.