# VIM incremental search, how to copy the matched string under cursor?

Tags: vim

In VIM, you can search a specified string. Then you can press <kbd>n</kbd> or <kbd>N</kbd> to navigate next or previous match. When you press <kbd>n</kbd> or <kbd>N</kbd>, the cursor will be moved to the matched text. My question is, how to quickly copy the matched text under cursor?

---

Edit:

What I need is the current match under cursor, not all matches in the document.

Comment: [This entry](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Copy_the_search_results_into_clipboard) in the Vim Tips FAQ covers this topic.

Comment: One might be also interested in the question "[Delete matching search pattern in VIM](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7842333/254635)".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can write a function extracting the match of the last search pattern
around the cursor, and create a mapping to call it.

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader>y :call setreg('"', MatchAround(@/), 'c')<cr>
function! MatchAround(pat)
    let [sl, sc] = searchpos(a:pat, 'bcnW')
    let [el, ec] = searchpos(a:pat, 'cenW')
    let t = map(getline(sl ? sl : -1, el), 'v:val."\n"')
    if len(t) > 0
        let t[0] = t[0][sc-1:]
        let ec -= len(t) == 1 ? sc-1 : 0
        let t[-1] = t[-1][:matchend(t[-1], '.', ec-1)-1]
    end
    return join(t, '')
endfunction
```

The function above determines the starting and ending positions of the match
and carefully takes out the matching text, correctly handling multiline
patterns and multibyte characters.

Another option is to create text object mappings (see `:help text-object`) for
operating on the last search pattern match under the cursor.

```
vnoremap <silent> i/ :<c-u>call SelectMatch()<cr>
onoremap <silent> i/ :call SelectMatch()<cr>
function! SelectMatch()
    if search(@/, 'bcW')
        norm! v
        call search(@/, 'ceW')
    else
        norm! gv
    endif
endfunction
```

To copy the current match using these mappings, use `yi/`.  As for other text
objects, it is also possible, for example, to visually select it using `vi/`,
or delete it using `di/`.

Comment: Note that the function above correctly handles one-character or multiline matches.

Comment: I would suggest using `v:register` in the mapping: `nnoremap <expr> <silent> <leader>y ':let @'.v:register.'=MatchAroundCursor(@/)<cr>'`

Comment: Thanks ib. I've pasted your function to my .vimrc. How to call them? I'm a newbie on VIM. Thanks.

Comment: The first line of the snippet above is a mapping.  If you have also copied that line to your `.vimrc` file, then, whenever the cursor is on a search pattern match, press the leader key (backslash, by default) followed by `y`, and the match will be yanked.

Comment: @Benoit:  Thanks for a good idea!  By the way, it's better to use `setreg()` to change the contents of a register (because of characterwise/linewise/blockwise mode issues).

Comment: @ib.: actually it seems that my idea was not that good. `v:register` seems not to be reset to default `"` after an operation involving another register. Try `"ayy<leader>y`. You do not expect `@a` to be overwritten...

Answer (score 7):

You want to execute the following

```
y//e
```

Overview:

The basic idea is after you search or press `n` or `N` the cursor will be at the beginning of the matched text. Then you yank to the end of the last search.

Explanation

- `y` will yank  from the current position through the following motion
- `//` searches using the last search pattern.
- `//e` The e flag will position the cursor at the end of the matched text

As a word of warning this will change the current search pattern, because it adds the `/e` flag. Therefore following `n` and/or `N` will move the cursor to the end of the match.

This is very similar to the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295278/is-there-a-way-to-copy-up-to-a-search-term-including-the-term).

Comment: Aside from annoying disadvantage of changing flags, this approach does *not* work as intended if the current match is only one character long!

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>y</kbd> and the text under the cursor will be copied to the unamed default register, then you can press <kbd>p</kbd> to paste.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should do it:

```
command! -register CopyExactMatchUnderCursor call s:CopyExactMatchUnderCursor('<reg>')

function! s:CopyExactMatchUnderCursor(reg)
    let cpos = getpos('.')
    let line = cpos[1]
    let idx = cpos[2] - 1
    let txt = getline(line)

    let mend = matchend(txt, @/, idx)

    if mend > idx
        let sel = strpart(txt, idx, mend - idx)

        let reg = empty(a:reg) ? '"' : a:reg
        execute 'let @' . reg . ' = sel . "\n"'
    end
endfunction
```

It grabs the cursor position first with `getpos` then searches for the end of the match (beginning with the column where the cursor is using `matchend`) and then returns the substring in the register provided - by default `"` is used.

All the necessary methods were basically in @eckes answer.

Comment: The function above does not solve the issue in general: it yanks nothing if the current match spans over multiple lines.